# iterating through buttons in sender.superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 6 buttons placed in a view and trying to change backgroundcolor accordingly:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    for(UIButton *btn in sender.superview){
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

following error msg:
[UIView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174191d30
2015-07-20 17:12:00.853 Raymio[20370:2209236] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174191d30'

i do get a compiler warning alerting this might happen, but am I not right getting senders superview like that?

EDIT: maybe I'm misunderstanding sth. I have a view controller(with a main view obv). Within that vc I have many views, incl a view where i have 6 buttons. I want to get only the 6 buttons in that specific view, hence I was trying to get superview of sender, thinking I got the view that i used to place the 6 buttons in.

Comment: Ummm, you can't iterate through a single view?

Comment: @davidcao im not sure if that was meant to be rhetorical or what. Anyway, Im iterating to x number of buttons in a single view?

Answer (score 1):

To enumerate subviews make sure you're referencing the subviews array:

```
for (UIButton *btn in sender.superview.subviews) {

    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: hm, is it necessary to send the isKindOfClass method, since the for is only looping through UIButton's anyway?

Comment: @DevilInDisguise if you're certain the only subviews are `UIButton` objects then no, it's not at all. I just wasn't sure if your view would contain other view types and cause another unexpected crash.

Comment: When sorting by oldest, the top post is the first post. In this question yes, my answer was first.

Answer (score 0):

The sender.superview doesn't conforms to the [NSFastEnumeration protocol](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/). Probably you'd like to iterate over sender.subviews(or sender.superview.subviews) like:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  for(UIButton *btn in sender.subviews){
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  }
  [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

EDIT:

As I said, you can define the outlet collection with your buttons:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Create these buttons, add them in this array (or attach via Interface Builder) and do the next:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  for(UIButton *btn in buttons){
     [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  }
  [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to get the subviews of a button; my buttons don't have any (sub)views in them.

Comment: I would suggest to define outlet collection of buttons with IBOutletCollection and iterate over this collection. In case the object is equal to sender - set background color to black. If not - set it to white.